# Junit: writing a test for a method that deletes an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, spring-data

What would be the most *exhaustive* tests that I could write for the following piece of code?

```
public void deleteFromPerson(person person) {
    person = personRepository.returnPerson(person.getId());
    personRepository.delete(person);
}
```

This method is within `a service` class. The method makes calls to a [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) that then calls it's `delete()` method on the entity.

If it is not possible to test if the entity is being deleted, is there any *other* `tests cases` I can run on the method?

Comment: You can test this by retrieving the person object making sure it is successfully retrieved and then deleting it and trying to retrieve it again. If you can't retrieve it the second time then the delete was successful.

Comment: *If it is not possible to test if the entity is being deleted* If you are writing a unit test, the responsibility of the test is to ensure that the `personRepository.delete` method is called, not that it actually works. If you are writing an integration test, you should create a `Person`, verify its existence, and then delete it and verify its non-existence.

Comment: Also test that deleting an invalid id or a valid id twice does as you expect.

Comment: you can test even listeners are called. you can test that the object is no longer in the database (evicting all from the L1/L2 caches before the check).

Comment: @Compass can you please show an example of testing the method is called ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two testing strategies. One is unit testing, i.e. making sure your service works. The other is integration/end-to-end testing, i.e. making sure everything plays nicely together.

You unit test stuff you own, you integration test everything you have. This is a pretty rough example using just your statement, plus some made up stuff where I can't fill in the blanks.

**Unit Tests**

Using Mockito

```
PersonRepository personRepository = mock(PersonRepository.class);

@TestSubject
PersonService personService = new PersonService(): 

@Test
public void unitTest() {
    personService.setPersonRepository(personRepository);
    Person person = new Person(1L);
    Person person2 = new Person(1L);

    when(personRepository.returnPerson(1L)).thenReturn(person2); //expect a fetch, return a "fetched" person;

    personService.deleteFromPerson(person);

    verify(personRepository, times(1)).delete(person2); //pretty sure it is verify after call
}
```

Using EasyMock...

```
@Mock
PersonRepository personRepository; //assuming it is autowired

@TestSubject
PersonService personService = new PersonService(): 

@Test
public void unitTest() {
    Person person = new Person(1L);
    Person person2 = new Person(1L);

    EasyMock.expect(personRepository.returnPerson(1L)).andReturn(person2); //expect a fetch, return a "fetched" person;
    personRepository.delete(person2);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall(); //expect a delete for person2 we plan to delete
    replayAll();

    personService.deleteFromPerson(person);

    verifyAll(); //make sure everything was called
}
```

Yes, this test looks like it is written rigidly, but that's really all you're testing in the unit test, anyways. You want the DB to fetch a Person from the database using an argument, hence why there are two `Person` objects, and you expect to delete that passed `Person` object, which is why you expect the call. Simple method yields simple test. You basically want to ensure you're interacting with your repository as you expect. Repository could be broken or null in actual implementation, but that doesn't change the fact that your service is implemented correctly.

**Integration Tests**

On the other hand, if you want to do an integration test, no mocking is used. Instead, you'll need to wire up everything like a **test DB** and repo. I'll leave that up to you since there's no reference for implementation.

```
@Test
public void integrationTestForAddAndDelete() {
    Person person = createDummyPersonForInsertion(); //static method that creates a test Person for you
    Person comparePerson;
    //make sure we haven't added the person yet
    Assert.assertNull(personService.getPerson(person));

    //add the Person
    comparePerson = personService.addPerson(person);
    Assert.assertNotNull(personService.getPerson(person));
    //add a rigorous compare method to make sure contents are the same, i.e. nothing is lost or transmuted incorrectly, ignoring ID if that is autogen
    //alternatively, you can create a unit test just for Person
    Assert.assertEquals(person, comparePerson); 

    //remove the Person
    personService.deleteFromPerson(person);
    Assert.assertNull(personService.getPerson(person));

    //test for exception handling when you try to remove a non-existent person;
    personService.deleteFromPerson(person);

    //test for exception handling when you try to remove null
    personService.deleteFromPerson(null);
}
```

In this case, you want to make sure your repo actually handles all the calls from the service. You know your service works from the unit test, but does the repo work from the service or have you configured something wrong

Comment: Thank you for the example, can you please quickly re-write what the example would be with using Mockito, I have never used easy mock so I find it quite confusing?

Comment: Added a rough idea of what Mockito would be. The syntax should be very similar if you switch to EasyMock if you know Mockito.